# Checking an array with views in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, view

I have a rails app with some views and I'd like to display something different if the view is the array doesn't contain any data. At the moment my view looks like this:

```
<% @trips.each do |trip| %>
  <p><%= trip.id %> | <%= trip.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

But is there a way I can show some different text if this doesn't have anything inside `@trips` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an if/else conditional check:

```
<% if (@trips != nil) then %>
  <p><%= trip.id %> | <%= trip.name %></p>
<% else %>
  <p>Some message</p>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if (@trips.blank?) then %>
  <p>Some message</p>
<% else %>
  <p><%= trip.id %> | <%= trip.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks JW8 which is more appropriate to use when? Thanks for taking the time to respond!

Comment: @davessh, they're equivalent - blank? is a bit more concise and utilizes a Ruby idiom, while the first way is similar checks in other languages.

Answer (score 7):

If you use partials:

**trips/_trip.html**

```
<p><%= trip.id %> | <%= trip.name %></p>
```

**your view**

```
<%= render @trips || 'No trip' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

sure, just use an if there, like this

```
<% if @trips.blank? %>
  <p>No trips</p>
<% else %>
  <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
    <p><%= trip.id %> | <%= trip.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a if statement and check if it is null or empty like this

```
<% if @trips.nil? || @trips.empty? %>
  <p>There are no trips</p>
<% else %>
  <% @trips.each do |trip| %>
    <p><%= trip.id %> | <%= trip.name %></p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Edit**

If working withing rails you would probably want to go with @trips.blank?, if you decide on another ruby framework or project then you can use the above if/else code to check if a array is null or empty

Comment: `@trips.nil? || @trips.empty?` can be written `@trips.blank?`, like in the ewiinnnnn answer

Comment: very true I didn't see his response until after I posted mine, I will edit